# Sorting string values without using any method/function

Tags: c#, .net

I trying to do sorting without use of any method or function

My Code :

```
   string[] names = { "Flag", "Nest", "Cup", "Burg", "Yatch", "Next" };                     
   string name = string.Empty;
   Console.WriteLine("Sorted Strings : ");

   for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < names.Length; j++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < names.Length; c++)
                {
                    if (names[i][c] > names[j][c])
                    {
                        name = names[i];
                        names[i] = names[j];
                        names[j] = name;
                    }
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
        }
```

Please let me bring any solution for this code ?

In this code i am getting **"Index was outside the bounds of the array"** exception

Comment: And why don't you want to use a method or function? It could be as easy as using a simple LINQ statement...

Comment: If you do not want to execute any piece of code (resulting in a call of a method or function) there is not much left available that can solve this.

Comment: What specifically are your problems with this code? You get better answers if you ask specific questions. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You don't need three loops over that `names` array. Two is enough. Or should that `c` loop go over `names[i].Length`?

Comment: @ReinderWit i did with use of method & function... i am try without that.... so oly like this...

Comment: Ok @HansKesting... but what i want to do with 2 loops ? I am not clear..

Comment: You get an exception because you try to loop over all characters in each input string, and do so using the length of the string list (names.Length) instead of the current one (names[I].Length). Then you compare each character with the previous name, but that doesn't have to be as long as the current one.

Answer (score 5):

```
        int temp = 0;
        int[] arr = new int[] { 20, 65, 98, 71, 64, 11, 2, 80, 5, 6, 100, 50, 13, 9, 80, 454 };
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i] > arr[j])
                {
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = temp;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement a sorting algorithm.

A very simple algorithm you can implement is the [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort):

```
string[] names = { "Flag", "Nest", "Cup", "Burg", "Yatch", "Next" };

for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    var x = names[i];
    var j = i;
    while(j > 0 && names[j-1].CompareTo(x) > 0)
    {
        names[j] = names[j-1];
        j = j-1;
    }
    names[j] = x;
}
```

Comment: @siva What do you mean, without algorithms? You're asking for an algorithm!

Comment: i am not saying like that... am trying with swapping & looping

Comment: @siva That's exactly what this answer does

Comment: Is this question about helping OP by telling what he did wrong, or is it about dumping your favorite sort implementation?

Comment: ya here used string CompareTo method. my expected result is without any use of method is this possible to do sorting?

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] names = { "Flag", "Next", "Cup", "Burg", "Yatch", "Nest" };
        string name = string.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("Sorted Strings : ");

        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            int c = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j < names.Length; j++)
            {
                if (j > i)
                {
                 Sort:
                    if (names[i][c] != names[j][c])
                    {
                        if (names[i][c] > names[j][c])
                        {
                            name = names[i];
                            names[i] = names[j];
                            names[j] = name;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        c = c + 1;
                        goto Sort;
                    }                        
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I you were conflicting in length of names array  and comparing string. Below is the working solution . I have tested it it's working now

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int min=0;

            string[] names = { "Flag", "Nest", "Cup", "Burg", "Yatch", "Next" };
            string name = string.Empty;
            Console.WriteLine("Sorted Strings : ");

            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length-1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < names.Length;j++ )
                {

                    if(names[i].Length < names[j].Length)
                           min =names[i].Length;
                    else
                            min =names[j].Length;
                    for(int k=0; k<min;k++)
                    {
                        if (names[i][k] > names[j][k])
                        {
                            name = names[i].ToString();
                            names[i] = names[j];
                            names[j] = name;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if(names[i][k] == names[j][k])
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }


            }
            for(int i= 0;i<names.Length;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[] {9,1,6,3,7,2,4};
        int temp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length;j++)
            {
                if(arr[i]>arr[j])
                {
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = temp;
                }
            }

            Console.Write(arr[i]+",");
        }
             Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: You should explain to him why you did what. Otherwise it is just a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
   string temp = "";
   for (int j = i + 1; j < names.Length; j++)
   {
      if (names[i].CompareTo(names[j]) > 0)
      {
           temp = names[j];
           names[j] = names[i];
           names[i] = temp;
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: string[] names = { "Flag", "Fig", "Nest", "Cup", "Burg", "Yatch", "Next" };

Answer (score 0):

```
public int compareing(string a, string b)
        {


            char[] one = a.ToLower().ToCharArray();
            char[] two = b.ToLower().ToCharArray();

            int ret = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < one.Length; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < two.Length; j++)
                {
                    Loop:
                    int val = 0;
                    int val2 = 0;

                    string c = one[i].ToString();
                    char[] c1 = c.ToCharArray();
                    byte[] b1 = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(c1);

                    string A = two[j].ToString();
                    char[] a1 = A.ToCharArray();
                    byte[] d1 = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a1);


                    int sec = d1[0];
                    int fir = b1[0];


                    if (fir > sec)
                    {
                        return ret = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (fir == sec)
                        {
                            j = j + 1;
                            i = i + 1;
                            if (one.Length == i)
                            {
                                return ret = 0;
                            }
                            goto Loop;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return 0;
                        }

                    }




                }


            }

            return ret;
        }
        public void stringcomparision(List<string> li)
        {
            string temp = "";
            for(int i=0;i<li.Count;i++)
            {
                for(int j=i+1;j<li.Count;j++)
                {

                    if(compareing(li[i],li[j])>0)
                    {
                        //if grater than it throw 1 else -1
                        temp = li[j];
                        li[j] = li[i];
                        li[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }


            Console.WriteLine(li);
        }
```

Comment: convert the string  char array. same way to done second char also. iterate the both characters.  check the each character ASCII code and compere.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            string temp = string.Empty;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < names.Length; j++)
            {
                if (names[i][0] > names[j][0])
                {
                    temp = names[i].ToString();
                    names[i] = names[j].ToString();
                    names[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            int l = 0;
            if (names[i][0] == names[i + 1][0])
            {
                string temp = string.Empty;
                if (names[i].Length > names[i + 1].Length)
                    l = names[i + 1].Length;
                else
                    l = names[i].Length;
                for (int j = 0; j < l; j++)
                {
                    if (names[i][j] != names[i + 1][j])
                    {
                        if (names[i][j] > names[i + 1][j])
                        {
                            temp = names[i].ToString();
                            names[i] = names[i + 1].ToString();
                            names[i + 1] = temp;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        foreach (var item in names)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your solution

Comment: First sort it based on all first letter of array string then sort it based on consecutive
letter of array string

Answer (score 0):

```
            string[] names = { "Flag", "Nest", "Cup", "Burg", "Yatch", "Next" };
            string temp = "";
            int tempX = 0, tempY = 0;
            int tempX1 = 0, tempY1 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<names.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i+1; j<names.Length; j++)
                {

                    if (((string)names[i])[0] > ((string)names[j])[0])
                    {
                        temp=(string)names[i];
                        names[i]=names[j];
                        names[j]=temp;
                    }
                    else if (((string)names[i])[0] == ((string)names[j])[0])
                    {
                        tempX=0; tempY=0;
                        tempX1=names[i].Length;
                        tempY1=names[j].Length;
                        while (tempX1 > 0 && tempY1 >0)
                        {
                            if (((string)names[i])[tempX] !=((string)names[j])[tempY])
                            {
                                if (((string)names[i])[tempX]>((string)names[j])[tempY])
                                {
                                    temp=(string)names[i];
                                    names[i]=names[j];
                                    names[j]=temp;

                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            tempX++;
                            tempY++;
                            tempX1--;
                            tempY1--;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi JasrajKumawat, welcome. Please consider adding an explanation and format properly your answer.

Comment: Above asked Question was Ambiguous, which is has been Corrected now. Previously user was not comparing conditions correctly. But now code is perfectly tested and working fine. Thank you.

Comment: What is the code doing? Adding an explanation to that question would indeed increase your answer's value.

Comment: my code is comparing  ASCII values, and it first checks value at '0' index of  array, and  above asked question compares all  characters so the code did not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using bubble sort:

Assume you have the array of names called `name`

The `tempName` is just to not change the original array *(You can use the original array instead)*

```cs
void sortStudentsAlphabetically()
{
     int nameIndex;
     string temp;
     string[] tempName = name;
     bool swapped = true;
    
     for(int i = 0; i < name.Length-1 && swapped ; i++)
     {
         swapped = false;

         for(int j = 0; j < name.Length-1; j++)
         {
             nameIndex = 0;
             recheck:
                 if (name[j][nameIndex]> name[j+1][nameIndex]) 
                 {
                     temp = tempName[j];
                     tempName[j] = tempName[j+1];
                     tempName[j+1] = temp;
                     swapped = true;
                 }
    
                 if (name[j][nameIndex] == name[j + 1][nameIndex])
                 {
                     nameIndex++;
                     goto recheck;
                 }
          }
   }
    
   foreach(string x in tempName)
   {
         Console.WriteLine(x);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**User Below code :**

```
int[] arrayList = new int[] {2,9,4,3,5,1,7};  
int temp = 0;  

for (int i = 0; i <= arrayList.Length-1; i++)  
{  
    for (int j = i+1; j < arrayList.Length; j++)  
    {  
        if (arrayList[i] > arrayList[j])  
        {  
            temp = arrayList[i];  
            arrayList[i] = arrayList[j];  
            arrayList[j] = temp;  
        }  
    }  
}  
Console.WriteLine("Sorting array in ascending order : ");  
foreach (var item in arrayList)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine(item);  
}  
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

```
Sorting array in ascending order : 1 2 3 4 5 7 9
```